# Getting the user's username - MyBB

Tags: php, forum, mybb

I was wondering how I would go about getting the user's username. What i want to do is display it like this:
`<a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=profile">Username here</a>`
I tried this:
`{$mybb->user['name']}'`
But that was unsuccessful and I cannot seem to find anything on Google.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

I am not that experienced with MyBB but after some research i found a few different ways.

```
$user = get_user($uid);
echo $user['username'];
```

or

```
global $db;
$qry = $db->query("SELECT uid FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE username = '".$usernamevar."'");
```

Comment: I actually got this to work:
`{$mybb->user['username']}`
Haha, I was 4 letters off. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but i thought that you had already checked the Database for the correct field names. Damn.

Comment: Thank you! Now I finally can continue integration of MyBB with my other applications which requires features such as browsing users.

Comment: As my first time helping someone on here, I can gladly say you are welcome! @xZero

Comment: can you please tell me, how you retrieved "uid" using $qry ?

Answer (score 2):

And you can combine all like this, i think.

```
<?php
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require ('global.php'); // be sure that u r running this php-code in the same
                        // directory of global.php, or else change the path.
if($mybb->user['uid'] > 0)
{
    $uid  = $mybb->user['uid'];
    $user = get_user($uid);
    $name = $user['username'];
}
    // custom else here: in case of not logged-in user
?>
<a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/usercp.php?action=profile"><?echo $name?></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this one into your template.

```
{$mybb->user['username']}
```

No need to use PHP for an existed variable.